# Is there any way that stores have other media than default on Magento?

Tags: magento, media

How can i separate, medias for different stores in Magento? For example: I have two stores "Store1", and Main Website Store by default. When i upload any image or something else on Store1, image has been stored in default media folder. 
    So my question is, is there any way to local storage for Store1 can be other media, that is not default? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento you can select different image for different website or store view. It works in the same way of the others field. From the admin interface, when you are on a product page, switch on your desired store view using the combo box on the left, then from the image section, uncheck the checkbox "use default value" and select the image that you want to display as base image, small image and thumb, relative to active store view. Than, if you want that an image is unavailable in your store view, you can use the "exclude" checkbox. If you are searching something to completely separate images, I think that Magento by default doesn't have this feature. I hope that's useful.

Comment: that is not it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896352/every-store-have-her-own-media-folder, this is so far i got with code. But thank you anyway. :)